# End running if, if else, else block in php

Tags: php, if-statement, exit

Is this ok?

```
$error_msg = "";
if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["name"])) {
  $error_msg="Not set name";
  exit();
} else if(!isset($_POST["radio1"]) || empty($_POST["radio1"])) {
  $error_msg="Not set question1";
  exit();
} else if(!isset($_POST["radio2"]) || empty($_POST["radio2"])) {
  $error_msg="Not set question2";
  exit();
} else { //... some code here }
//continues here after exit???
//Somewhere code printing first cahched error message
```

I'm not sure about behaviour of exit() here. What I wanna do is when i reach first condition fail, I set the $error_msg and exit the if, else if, else block and continue execution after it on line I marked "continues here after exit???" Where I print the error message and do other things like print the form etc.

**Edit:**
To the reactions - I kind of thought it probably end the script but. So I know I was wrong,but my question was actually about what to do to end only "if else block". What will work for me? Something like break, return?
Cause if if is not set name and radio2 the error message will be "Not set question2" instead of just "Not set name", cuz i wanna only first occured mistake.

Comment: `exit()` will 'exit' the script, not just the `if()` statement. If any of those conditions is true, the script ends there. Maybe a read of the [documentation](http://uk1.php.net/exit) is in order?

Comment: No need for `exit()` remove them all

Comment: better place for this question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: but what happens if not there are two fails? for example I'm user and I don't set the name and the question 2. And I wanna end execution the if else block after first user fail.

Comment: That is what happens. Once any condition is met, the if else block stops on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for `exit()` remove them all. There is no need to "end" the if else block. Once **any** condition is met, it ends.

```
$error_msg = "";
if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["name"])) {
  $error_msg="Not set name";
} else if(!isset($_POST["radio1"]) || empty($_POST["radio1"])) {
  $error_msg="Not set question1";
} else if(!isset($_POST["radio2"]) || empty($_POST["radio2"])) {
  $error_msg="Not set question2";
} else { 

    // Code to run if all post variables are set correctly.

}

if (!empty($error_msg)) {

    // Display error message - echo $error_msg;

}
```

Comment: Ty, but not answer to my question. I edited it and make it more clear what was the point since begining.

Comment: This is the answer to your question. Remove all the `exit()`, they are not needed. The `if else` stops executing once any condition is met. My code above will do what you need.

Comment: Re edit: It rly ends execution of the the whole block? Won't check other else if? I'm used to write programs in java and it has different   behaviour.

Comment: It's not different in Java. It's exactly the same... Once a condition is met, no other conditions are evaluated.

Comment: Ok than. It's strange but good to know. Just theese diferences between programing languages.Thx.

Comment: Well won't argue with you and will check it in java to in free time but I thought it's like I said, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` will end the rest of the PHP script, you dont need to use it in this context.

The if statement will only process the `else` and `else if`s if the condition(s) above it fails

Read this for more information on `exit()`: [PHP.net Exit()](https://www.php.net/exit)